# getGender() returning null with isMale

Tags: java

Whenever I run the `getGender()` it shows as `null`. It's the `isMale` that confuses me.

```
public Student(String sid, String name,  boolean isMale)
{       
    this.sid = sid;
    this.name = name;
    this.isMale = isMale;
    courses = "30202";  // default is empty
}
```

I have made it be able to return a value but it returns it as "true" or "false" and doesn't return it as "Male" or "Female" but this is the code in which returns it as null. I'm at a standstill.

Comment: What's `gender`? I don't see anywhere that it is defined or assigned a value.

Comment: Links to full code are frowned upon here at StackOverflow; please be prepared to post all **relevant** code in your question.

Comment: Sorry @Qix - I tried to look for site rules before posting but couldn't seem to find them, thank you. I won't do it again.

Comment: @jayyy Did you try looking up at the big *Help* dropdown at the top of the site? ;)

Comment: @Qix well know you say it I feel like an idiot, haha. I guess its due to a mixture of being at the libary for a hours and being very tired ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor doesn't set your field `String gender`. You could,

```
public Student(String sid, String name,  boolean isMale){       
  this.sid = sid;
  this.name = name;
  this.isMale = isMale;
  this.gender = (isMale) ? "Male" : "Female";
  courses = "30202";  // default is empty
}
```

Of course, then your output might be

```
Male: Female
```

So, I think you really wanted

```
// System.out.println("Male: " + getGender());
System.out.println("Gender: " + getGender());
```

Then you would get

```
Gender: Male
```

or

```
Gender: Female
```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. I was too focused on isMale I don't know why, it's the first time i've seen it before probably. Thank you.

Comment: What about in the case of a shemale?

Comment: @LeatherFace *He* would either identify as male; or *she* would identify as female. I guess you only care about MTF trans, but FTM trans would have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your isMale variable indicates whether the person isMale or not.

You should change the getGender method so that it will return "Male" when isMale == true and "Female" when isMale == false.

```
   /**
     * Get the gender of the student, i.e. "Male" or "Female"
     *
     * @return The String "Male" if the student is male,
     *         otherwise "Female".
     */
    public String getGender()
    {
        if(isMale) {
          gender = "Male";
        }
        else{
          gender = "Female";
        }
       return gender;
    }
```

Comment: This will not compile due to the unreachable return statement.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand it more! Thank you thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that sets the `gender` field in your class.

In general, you shouldn't have both an `isMale` variable and a `gender` variable. That's redundant. You can derive one from the other, and `isMale` is a better implementation because you have only two states (not trying to be anti-trans here, that's simply the basic assumption in most student assignment).

Comment: It's just how it was given to me.